# Problem with reiterating BASE URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I somehow messed up my htaccess file which altered my website base URL. The htaccess file is in my public-html directory. My web site URL is supposed to be: http://voidnow.org

I was trying to redirect traffic from voidnow.org to voidnow.org/community, but, I obviously messed it up, royally.

Attempts to reach that voidnow.org on the web take everyone to the following URL:

/community/http://voidnow.org/community/http:/voidnow.org/community/http:/voidnow.org/community/http:/voidnow.org/...

(that erroneous URL reiterates for hundreds of characters.)

Can someone help me with the correct htaccess command to restore my correct URL direction in my htaccess file. I tried removing the htaccess file, and it has no effect. I tried restoring the original htaccess file, with no positive result.

Thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 0):

If you were using 301 redirects then try clearing browser cache & restart (browser) .. or try another browser -- **modern browsers do cache permanent redirects**.

Right now your site works fine for me -- no redirect at all.